# notification center observer to check an NSTextView wont work right

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm using a notification center observer to check an NSTextView

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:  #selector(testest), name: NSTextView.didEndEditingNotification, object: nil)
```

it works but the thing is, i got two nstextview and it automaticly picks up on one

even when i specify its name in obejct?? why is that?

like this

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(testest), name: NSTextView.didEndEditingNotification, object: BoxText)
```

**Update**: It acutlay picks up on both of my NSTextViews how do i specify one?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you get notifications from one text view when you don't specify the object? Which one? Do you get notifications from both text views when you do specify an object? Did you know there's a delegate method `textDidEndEditing(_:)`?

Comment: So do you want do have two text views connected to the same selector and you need a way to know which one it is calling it?

Comment: hi leo, i would like to do the same thing but with a textview instead of a textfield

Comment: @LeoDabus What does the `object` parameter do? The documentation says "The object whose notifications the observer wants to receive; that is, only notifications sent by this sender are delivered to the observer.".

Comment: @Willeke you can option click the property. **An object that the poster wishes to send to observers.
Typically this is the object that posted the notification.** So cast it from `Any` to `NSTextView` and check if it is equal to the textview you have the connected with the IBOutlet.

Comment: @Willeke https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notification/1779839-object check the Discussion note.

Comment: @LeoDabus we're talking about different `object`s. Which `object` do you mean in "The object has nothing to do with it. You can pass any object to the selector."? I was talking about the `object` passed to `addObserver`.

Comment: @Willeke If you pass nil, the notification center doesn’t use a notification’s sender to decide whether to deliver it to the observer. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1415360-addobserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass nil all NSTextView in your view controller will receive the notification. Just create an IBOutlet to each NSTextView, cast the notification object to NSTextView and check if it is equal to each of them. If you would like to have a selector to fire just for a certain text view you need to pass it as the object parameter:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textViewLeft: NSTextView!
    @IBOutlet var textViewRight: NSTextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // If you pass nil all NSTextView in your view controller will receive the notification
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didEndEditing), name:  NSTextView.didEndEditingNotification, object: nil)
        // If you would like to have a selector to fire just for a certain text view you need to pass it as the object parameter
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didEndEditingTextViewLeft), name:  NSTextView.didEndEditingNotification, object: textViewLeft)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didEndEditingTextViewRight), name:  NSTextView.didEndEditingNotification, object: textViewRight)

    }

    @objc func didEndEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
        if (obj.object as? NSTextView) == textViewLeft {
            print(#function, "textViewLeft")
        } else if (obj.object as? NSTextView) == textViewRight {
            print(#function,"textViewRight")
        }
    }

    @objc func didEndEditingTextViewLeft(_ obj: Notification) {
        print(#function)
    }

    @objc func didEndEditingTextViewRight(_ obj: Notification) {
        print(#function)
    }
}
```

Comment: works but i needed to use didChangeTypingAttributesNotification to the function to work when the text is changed in the textview, thx u